# Committee Voting Choice

Tags: probability, game-theory

Let's say you're in a group of 20 people, and each person has 3 votes for different people. They're all voting for a 5 member committee, and the 5 people who get the most votes win. Ties are resolved with a revote. You want to be elected, everyone running can vote, and you can vote for yourself.

The question: Is it more beneficial for you to vote for the people you think will win, or people you don't think will win?

My thinking: If you vote for people you think will win, then you're eliminating the chance of potential rivals (who you're not sure will win) winning that are close to you in terms of votes. If you vote for people who you think won't win, you're lowering the chance of the people you think will win by not voting for them.

Comment: Shouldn't you just cast all three of your votes for yourself?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't vote for the same person twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no control over the number of votes you receive nor the number of votes everyone else receives.  Whether or not you vote for the rival, you must still have to have more votes than your competitor.  The only action you can take that minimizes the number of votes from your competitor is to not vote for them.  Therefore you should vote for yourself and "throw away" your other two votes (vote for anybody who is not likely to win).

If you vote for a rival, all you do is help that rival; who, if they can beat your competitor, may *also* be able to help *you*.  Any rival of a competitor is a competitor to you and you shouldn't help *any* competitors.

Comment: Question: if your rivals do this, and they all vote on the "least likely" winner, which you all think is the same person, doesnt that person win?

Comment: I believe in that case, you should vote for two random people (regardless of your perceived likelihood for that person to win or lose).  If you honestly believed that everyone would do this, then it would simply redefine who your competitors were so you just wouldn't vote for the same "losers" that everyone else did.  But you probably see the problem--everyone else knows this too and so you again need to change who you vote for.

Comment: This is why i like game theory. Its all about counter intuitive and multilevel strategies.

Comment: It becomes something you'd have to compute numerically because for each different type of player, you would likely choose a different optimal strategy.  Then you have to think about how many voters are likely to employ each of the different possible strategies and then find the best expected outcome given those likely sets actors.

Comment: If everyone employs the identical, optimal, strategy then the best you can do is a random outcome.  You have to somewhat assume that the person who best estimates the others' behaviors will win on average (assuming each person chooses the optimal strategy given their expected behavior of the rest of the players).

Answer (score 1):

You vote once for yourself (assuming you can only do so once) and then after that, it depends. If there is someone you know will get more votes than you, vote for them, as then your vote does effect you. If no such people exist, vote for the people least likely to win.